# Adding materials to a list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having trouble adding materials to a list. My objects have multiple materials assigned to them and I am adding all of that to a specified list. The error I receive is `cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Material[]' to 'UnityEngine.Material'`. What am I doing wrong here?

```
public GameObject[] myObjs;
private List<Material> myObjs_mats = new List<Material>();

void Start () {
         for(int i = 0; i<myObjs.Length; i++){
             myObjs_mats.Add(myObjs[i].GetComponent<Renderer>().materials);
     }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetComponent<Renderer>().materials` returns an array. But since you're using the `Add` method you can only add one item at a time.

So either call `Add` in a Loop, or just use `AddRange` instead of `Add`.